# Controlling CSS Transitions with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, fade

I have a simple opacity fade on an image, currently just using css.

It works fine..

CSS

```
ul#project li img {
opacity: 0.5;
transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

ul#project li img:hover{ opacity: 1;}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="project" class="inner clearfix">
    <li class="tv-thumb 67">
        <a href="#" rel="link">
        <img class='large-image' src='image.jpg' />         
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible with jQuery to pause or hold the animation at all, for example you hover over it fades up to full opacity, you leave and before fading back there is a pause of 5 seconds?

This possible, i'm keen to only use the one image thats all really..

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like  this:

css

```
 #project li a{
    opacity:0.5;
    }
```

js-1

```
$('#project li a').bind('mouseover',function(){

  $(this).fadeTo(0,1);

}).bind('mouseout',funcion(){

 $(this).delay(5000).fadeTo(0,0.5);

});
```

or js-2

```
 $('#project li a').on('mouseover',function(){

      $(this).fadeTo(0,1);

    });

 $('#project li a').on('mouseout',funcion(){

     $(this).delay(5000).fadeTo(0,0.5);

    });
```

or js-3

```
$('#project li a').on('mouseenter',function(){

      $(this).fadeTo(1500,1);

    });

$('#project li a').on('mouseleave',function(){

      $(this).delay(5000).fadeTo(1500,0.5);

    });
```

?

EDITED :If you want to translate css to jquery do not use css and use jquery (in jsfiddle you can remove css transitions and more over), then in your case you should bind the event to the main img parent so the  element, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/pmf68/8/

EDIT 2 :

if you neednot jumping opacity try this instead http://jsfiddle.net/pmf68/10/

Comment: If this is 1.7+, .on() would be preferable to bind().

Comment: Thank you everyone i'm a bit confused though, is this instead of the CSS? I added the above but nothing happened...

Comment: .on() is basically live, bind, and delegate all wrapped into one, with the bonus of increased efficiency. If you look at jQuery internals, you'll see that those three methods are all deprecated and are just masks for event delegation with .on(). Plus, it says so in the manual. :)

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work, does it work with the css or independent, i've tried both and no luck.. :(

Comment: @user4630 try pasting your code on jsfiddle.net and then put link here ;)

Comment: check here, you can remove css rules for transitions then you have to wait 5 seconds after **mouseout** :) http://jsfiddle.net/pmf68/8/

Comment: Thank you, that has the time element but its not fading? Its just jumping from one opacity to another...?

Comment: yep as you askwed, it is jumping from opacity to opacity, anyway you can joke on fadeTo(); cause the first param sets the delay in fading so : **fadeTo(delay,opacity);**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19821/discussion-between-user4630-and-ispuk)